# Firebase iOS returning when creating users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm having a hard time figuring out why firebase is returning the error code **17011** (which according to Firebase documentation is a user not found error), when creating a user with email and password even after deleting all the users in the database and authentication sections of the firebase console. Although the user is created successfully and added to firebase realtime database the error code keeps popping up. Below is a complete error that gets printed out on the console:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17011 "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., error_name=ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND})!

The complete class:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var emailField: RoundedCornerTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: RoundedCornerTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

emailField.delegate = self
passwordField.delegate = self

}

@IBAction func signupLoginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

if emailField.text != nil && passwordField.text != nil {
if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in //Sign in

  if error == nil {

      if let user = user {

          if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

              let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]

              DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)

          } else {   

              let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]

              DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
          }
      }

      print ("Firebase: Success authentication with Firebase.")

      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

  } else {
   if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code){
switch errorCode {
 case.wrongPassword:
        self.showAlert("You entered an invalid password please try again!")
    default:
            self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
          print("Creating user error 1 \(error.debugDescription)!")
       }
   }

  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in //creating a user

      if error == nil {
          if let user = user {
              if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { 
                  let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                  DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
              } else { 
                  let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                  DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
              }
      } else {
              if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
                  switch errorCode {
                  case .invalidEmail:
                      self.showAlert("You entered an invalid email!")
                  case .userNotFound:
                      self.showAlert("User not found")
                  default:
                      print("Creating user error 2 \(error.debugDescription)!")
                      self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
                  }
              }
          }
          print("Firebase: user created successfully")
          self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
             }
           })
         }
      })
   }
 }
}

}
```

And block of code that the error occurs:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in 
if error == nil {
    if let user = user {
        if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
            DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)   
        }   
        else { 
                let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
                DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
             }
    }

    print ("Firebase: Success authentication with Firebase.")

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}     
else {

    if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code){   
       switch errorCode {
            case.wrongPassword:
                self.showAlert("You entered an invalid password please try again!")
            default:
                self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
                print("Creating user error \(error.debugDescription)!")
       }
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in 
       if error == nil {
           if let user = user { 
               if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { 
                   let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                   DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)   
                } 
               else { 
                   let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
                   DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
                }

            } 
            else {
               if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
                   switch errorCode { 
                        case .invalidEmail:
                            self.showAlert("You entered an invalid email!")
                        case .userNotFound:
                            self.showAlert("User not found")
                        default:
                            print("Creating user error \(error.debugDescription)!")
                            self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
                    }
               }
           }
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
```

The error occurs in the Auth.auth().signIn else block below:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in 
   if error == nil {
       if let user = user { 
           if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { 
               let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
               DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)   
            } 
           else { 
               let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
               DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
            }

        } 
        else {
           if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
               switch errorCode { 
                    case .invalidEmail:
                        self.showAlert("You entered an invalid email!")
                    case .userNotFound:
                        self.showAlert("User not found")
                    default:
                        print("Creating user error \(error.debugDescription)!")
                        self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
                }
           }
       }
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Could anyone provide a solution to resolve?

P.S Yes I imported firebase to the project and pods are up to date also email/password sign in method in the authentication section of firebase console is enabled.

Comment: If you create a user in the authentication tab of the Firebase console can they login?

Comment: @DoesData Yes they can login with no problem at all

Comment: Are your `email` and `password` correct?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 yes they are problem occurs when creating a new users. But If I quit the app and restart again and try login in with the same email and password that previously shows the error it logs in with no problem. And when I create a user from the firebase console they too can log in. The error only occurs when trying to create a new user. Even though the user is created and stored in the database.

Comment: I think problem is that when you create user, you try to sign in without signing out , because when you create a user you are already signed in

Comment: Hi, are you sure you are finishing the block like when signing up/creating a firebase user?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I don't think that's the issue

Comment: @Glenn Yes the finished I'm sure of it

Comment: I don't think there is enough code here to determine the issue. There doesn't appear to be any issues with the code above. The only thing that makes sense is that you are creating the user and then signing them in. If you close the app after creating a user and then you are able to sign in the issue is with that you are doing after the user is created. You even state that the user is created in Firebase so something else must be going wrong. Post some more code

Comment: @DoesData I think the issue is in error code block before the Auth.auth.createUser block it is disrupting the flow of events the error is ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND there will always be this error since the user is yet to exist. And the code is jumping into the else block to create a user because a user with such credential doesn't exists.

Comment: Again your current code is not enough. As it stands looking at only the code provided it looks like you are trying to sign in BEFORE you create the user thus the user is never found because they don't exist. Then the create user fires the user is created and when you restart the app you can sign in.... Second request provide more code...

Comment: @DoesData you are right some edits have been added. and that's the end of the code. The problem is here
     `if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code){   
           switch errorCode {
                case.wrongPassword:
                    self.showAlert("You entered an invalid password please try again!")
                default:
                    print("Creating user error \(error.debugDescription)!")
           }
        }`
 it's stopping the flow of events as you can see the error is user not found

Comment: You keep responding by saying the same thing the error is here.... We need to know how you got there. This can't be the only code you have.... post the whole create user / sign in class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154390/discussion-between-9it3e1-and-doesdata).

Comment: After seeing code , i think problem is  that you are signing in with same email and password before creating the user, I dont think that is possible since user is not created yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code for a while, I released that the all the errors handling sign in should be handled before entering the createUser() function. And since there is .userNotfound error in Firebase Auth. calling the createUser() in the case.userNotFound solves the problem as shown below:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error == nil {
            if let user = user {
                if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                    let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                    DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
                } else {
                    let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
                    DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
                }
            }

            print ("Firebase: Success authentication with Firebase.")

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                switch errorCode {

                case.wrongPassword:
                    self.showAlert("You entered an invalid password please try again!")

                case.userNotFound:
                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let user = user {
                                if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                                    let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                                    DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData)
                                } else {
                                    let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
                                    DataService.instance.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
                                }

                            } else {
                                if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                                    switch errorCode {

                                    case .invalidEmail:
                                        self.showAlert("You entered an invalid email!")

                                    case .userNotFound:
                                        self.showAlert("User not found")

                                    default:
                                        print("Creating user error 2 \(error.debugDescription)!")
                                        self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    })

                default:
                    self.showAlert("Unexpected error \(errorCode.rawValue) please try again!")
                    print("Creating user error \(error.debugDescription)!")
                }
            }
        }
 })
```